# register 3 axis to 3 points

Tags: vector, transformation, computational-geometry

I try to register a set of 3 lines to a set of 3 points. The Coordinate System of both sets are not the same. So I need to find the rotation and translation of the lines so they pass through the points. Does anyone know a good method to do so?
little bit of Context:
the lines are the axis of a drilling wholes obtained by CT Scans and the points are marker obtained from a Motion Capture System. The markers were on the screw inserted into the drilling wholes. I need to match them in order that I can register the CT Data to the MotionCapture System
Thanks for any suggestion,
JG

I tried to match the distance of the three MoCap points to a set of points on the axis. The points estimated on the axis were not at the location as expected.
I also tried Horn's Method (which also not yielded the result expected):
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26186-absolute-orientation-horn-s-method

Afterwards I would rotate the new points to the MoCap point with a svd based method.

Here an example (MATLAB):

```
MoCap_points = [243.9669  203.8436  215.5850
              104.2774  117.8749   85.7087
             -113.6220 -106.1354 -102.1162];
```

Axis line in form r_0 + s_i*V_dir :

```
r_0_ = 1.0e+03 *[0.6269    0.6139    0.6055
                 -1.6006   -1.6178   -1.6009
                 -0.3004   -0.2963   -0.3010];
V_dir =     [0.6183    0.0112   -0.2819
            0.2555   -0.3098    0.3367
            0.7432    0.9507    0.8984];
```

Comment: Is this problem 2D or 3D ??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am sorry I haven't responded over christmas

Comment: A line constrained to pass by a point still has two degrees of freedom. Your problem is undetermined.

Comment: But 3 lines that correspond to individual 3 points are determined. Which means I try to find a rigid body transformation of the 3 lines in order that they pass through the 3 points or at least the best fit for this problem